# Correctly rounding a trigonometric function for single-precision

Tags: floating-point, rounding, numerical-methods, ieee-754

I want a correctly rounded (round to nearest ties to even) single-precision trigonometric function (0.5 ulp error). 
I can use either the CORDIC algorithm or one of the polynomial approximation methods to obtain a higher-precision result, say double-precision.

1. Is casting the result from double to float will correctly round to nearest? (For example, if implemented in C with the GCC compiler.)
2. Do I need to implement my own rounding method for it to be correctly rounded? If so, may I use fewer bits? For example, if I use CORDIC, will (roughly) 35 bits will be enough (32 bits + 3 bits for rounding)?
3. Somehow similar to (2). How much the result in higher precision must be exact? (For example, is an absolute error of 1e-15 is enough?)

Comment: This depends on the function, and finding the answers is not easy. There was a project CRLibm, which is now defunct, that involved answering this question for various functions, and I believe they had some success with the basic trigonometric functions. Their old web site is not responding, but you may be able to find some of their academic publications and other information by searching for “CRLibm”. Also, I think there is a project continuing work in the same vein, but its name escapes me at the moment.

Comment: I think CRLibm was looking largely at double precision (IEEE-754 basic 64-bit binary floating-point), though. Answers might be more readily available for single precision. (Incidentally, “CRLibm” stands for “Correctly Rounded Libm”, and a goal was to provide correctly rounded math routines with known bounds on the execution times, and good execution times on average.)

Comment: Take a look at Vincent Lefèvre's work for some idea of what's involved, e.g.: https://hal.inria.fr/inria-00072594

Comment: @EricPostpischil According to [wayback-machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20170128033523/http://lipforge.ens-lyon.fr:80/www/crlibm/) : _The effort of CRlibm developers has moved to the MetaLibm project. There will be no release of CRlibm after 1.0beta5._

Comment: Anybody know the status of single precision? I would not be surprised if CRlibm had produced data for the single precision routines in the course of pursing double precision.

Comment: So, according to CRLibm's manual and the paper provided by Mark, the correctly rounded to nearest implementation is not practical for most purposes? (which explains why most libraries are not). Meaning, that I should relax my requirements to 1 ulp or so?

Comment: @Daniel: A reason that correct rounding is hard is that rounding can add .5 ULP. Suppose your goal is .6 ULP. If you compute (with extra precision) an estimate within .1 ULP, and the estimate happens to be just slightly on the wrong side of the rounding point (midway between representable values), the rounding will add almost another .5 ULP. But .1 plus .5 is .6, so you meet the goal. In contrast, if your goal is .5 ULP (correct rounding, apart from ties), and you compute an estimate within 10**-999 ULP, but it happens to be just slightly on the wrong side of the rounding point,…

Comment: … then rounding adds almost .5 ULP, and your total is just over .5 ULP. In other words, if you want correct rounding, any positive amount of error in your pre-rounding estimate could result in a wrong answer. So, apparently you need to compute an infinitely precise result? Not quite. The way around this is to examine the function and prove that, if you compute with a certain accuracy, then none of the cases happen the land too near a rounding point. That is hard.

Comment: A conclusion from the above is that, yes, relaxing your goal even slightly makes it a lot easier. If you have a double precision `cos` that is, say, accurate with 73 ULP of the `double` format, then rounding it to float guarantees a result correct within .5 + 73/2\*\*29 ULP of the `float` format (because the `cos` guarantees accuracy of 73/2\*\*29 ULP and unfortunate rounding might add another .5, so the total is .5 + 73/2\*\*29). Another conclusion is that, to guarantee a post-rounding result accurate within 1 ULP, a pre-rounding result accurate within .5 ULP suffices.

Comment: Thank you @EricPostpischil. Did you mean 0.73? So casting to float is a reasonable method of rounding (from the pre-rounded result)?

Comment: @Daniel: No, 73. I plucked it out of the air as an example of how a very loose `double` routine would make a very tight `float` routine. Yes, if you have a good pre-rounded result in `double`, converting it to `float` should round it.